# special character displayed as question mark in rdf

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I am using oracle reports 12c. While running report special character in varchar2 column is displayed as ? in the pdf output of the report. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If

- "special character" is correctly saved into the database (which means that database's **NLS settings** know how to properly interpret those characters). UTF8 usually helps
- report (the RDF file), in its Paper Layout editor, uses **font** which is capable of properly displaying those "special characters"

then there shouldn't be any problems.

Therefore, check what's really stored into the table (because, you might *think* that you stored characters properly, but - in reality - you stored *garbage*) and that you chose correct font.

P.S. As reports run on server (WebLogic, right?), such a font should be installed there as well, not only on your own PC, i.e. a computer where you *develop* reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the database directly using something like SQL Developer, try running the query below but replacing `Test String` with the actual string you are having issues displaying.  It may help identify what the character is that is giving you issues.

Most likely, it issue has to do with character encoding or a character set either in the database or in the reports application not supporting the character you are trying to display.

#### Query

This should help identify what the problematic character is

```
WITH
    test_string AS (SELECT 'Test String' AS val FROM DUAL),
    chars
    AS
        (    SELECT SUBSTR (ts.val, LEVEL, 1)     AS single_char
               FROM test_string ts
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (ts.val))
SELECT single_char,
       ASCII (single_char)                   AS ascii_code,
       CONVERT (single_char, 'AL32UTF8')     AS char_as_al32utf8
  FROM chars;
```

#### Result

```
   SINGLE_CHAR    ASCII_CODE    CHAR_AS_AL32UTF8
______________ _____________ ___________________
T                         84 T
e                        101 e
s                        115 s
t                        116 t
                          32
S                         83 S
t                        116 t
r                        114 r
i                        105 i
n                        110 n
g                        103 g
```